# Is there a website that provide SYN packets from various operating system?

Tags: tcp

I am looking for such a website that have SYN packets from various operating systems. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

[nmap's os db](http://nmap.org/book/nmap-os-db.html). Be warned, they're serious about the licensing restrictions.